# Anyone know a good way to automate clicking in an HTML <canvas> element in Python? (E.g., in a pixel canvas)

Tags: python, canvas, bots

Last year reddit released a social experiment for April Fool's, a pixel canvas that allowed users to click a color into any pixel on the grid; and they would have to wait a certain amount of time before they could click again. After the experiment ended, several duplicate sites sprang up, among them http://origami64.net/place.php.

I wanted to make a bot that would go and automatically click on a given pixel in the canvas, and since I was getting enrolled in a Python class at that point in time, I figured I would learn Python in order to do it. Initially I tried to use one of the bots for the original canvas as a template (https://github.com/hithroc/fixRD/blob/master/img.py), but the new canvas was too different for that to work.

When I discovered the selenium module though, I thought it would be a good idea to try it out, so I compiled this code:

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://origami64.net/place.php")
black=driver.find_element_by_id('#222')
black.click()
canvas=driver.find_element_by_id('c0')
time.sleep(5)
x=0
y=0
while (1):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(x, y)")
    canvas.click()
    x=x+1
    y=y+1
    time.sleep(2.5)
```

I know, pretty insignificant. And it doesn't doesn't do much except click on one spot on the canvas.

So how do I get it to click on other pixels? I tried implementing move_to_element_with_offset, but that continuously resulted in MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException errors, because the canvas is larger than the viewport in the window. So you have to zoom out to see the whole canvas in order for it to be possible to place a pixel.

I spent a few weeks trying to get move_to_element_with_offset to work for me, and even after I did, I was unable to accomplish my goal, because it turns out that the offset coordinates in selenium are not counted by pixels of the elements, but by literal pixels on the screen. So unless there is a way to get the zoom perfectly linear with the pixels on the screen in ratio to those in the < canvas> element, I can't really choose the extent of my offset.

So selenium seems to be a dead end for me. I realize that when the canvas receives a click, though, there is a JavaScript code that initiates at http://origami64.net/jscripts/place.js. If I can get the portion of the script that determines where the mouse location is when the "click" occurred to run at my command, and I can feed the mouse x, y coordinates with my own values, maybe then I could make this work? I don't know.

Honestly I'm not sure which direction to go at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, through research I have determined that it is not possible to do this easily. It is much more convenient to just use web scraping if you want to bot.

Comment: This is not really an answer (to your own question). If it is possible via web scraping, then the answer should explain how web scraping can be used to automate the pixel clicking you were looking for.